# Compare wchar_t's while using Module32Next() in a while loop

Tags: c++, string, winapi, compare

So I have taken a module snapshot of a process. I want to scan it for a specific DLL. If it is found, it will break the loop. If it's not found, It should print DLL not found. Using TlHelp32 I have the following lines of code:

```
while (wcscmp(entryDllStrucs.szExePath, file_path) != 0)
    {
        LPCWSTR pre = entryDllStrucs.szModule;
        Module32Next(dllpathSnapShot, &entryDllStrucs);
        LPCWSTR post = entryDllStrucs.szModule;
        if (pre == post) {cout << "Failed to find DLL\n"; break;}

    }
```

file_path is a wchar_t is the path to the file. It all works except the part where if the DLL is not found it breaks. Thte LPCWSTR pre will change as Module32Next is called. I tried to also make it `const LPCWSTR pre = entryDllStructs.szModule` and `const LPCWSTR post = entryDllStructs.szModule` But that didn't work. Casting to a DWORD long doesn't work either.

Help will be appreciated!

C++/Win32Api

Comment: `pre == post` is always true, because they both point to the same `entryDllStrucs.szModule`. To do a proper comparison use `std::wstring` to save the string. But then the comparison will always return false. I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish. Show MCVE with expected output.

Comment: I'm trying to print "Failed to find DLL" when a DLL can't be located in a process, and if the DLL is located, I want the program execution to continue on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `pre` and `post` variables are pointers. And they both point to the same member of the same `MODULEENTRY32` struct. So comparing them is pointless, they always will contain the same value. Also - your entire approach is wrong, since your code will output "Failed to find DLL\n" string on each iteration of the while loop. Also since you never check `Module32Next` result, your loop will never end if target dll is not found.

```
BOOL fFound = FALSE;
while (TRUE)
{
   if(!wcscmp(entryDllStrucs.szExePath, file_path))
   {
     fFound = TRUE;
     break;
   }

   if(!Module32Next(dllpathSnapShot, &entryDllStrucs))
     break;
}

if(!fFound)
{
   cout << "Failed to find DLL\n"; break;
}
```